# Prove that the functions are convex

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**My question** Consider the following functions on strictly positive variables:
$$
\begin{aligned}
h_1(x) &:=\frac{1}{x} \\
h_2(x, y) &:=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x+y} \\
h_3(x, y, z) &:=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{1}{y+z}-\frac{1}{x+z}+\frac{1}{x+y+z}
\end{aligned}
$$
$\bigcirc$ Prove that $h_1, h_2, h_3$, and in general $h_n$ are convex!.
**My attempt:** I can prove that $h_1$, $h_2$, $h_3$ is convex function by computing their second derivative. But in general $h_n$, I think it isn't a good way. I tried to find the component but i can't do it.

Comment: Pick two points on $h_n(x)$ and parameterize the line that connects them. Then, for any points in that interval, show that $h_n(x)$ lies below that line.

Comment: I used to think about using the definition. But i still can't solve the problem @Alborz

Comment: I noticed that if we have a set of variables $X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n \}$ then in general we have $h_n(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\frac1{\sum_{x_k \in X}x_k} + \sum_{x_k \in X} h_{n-1}(x_1,x_2,...,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},...x_n)$. Maybe you can you work this into a proof by induction?

Comment: I used to think about this idea. But I can't do it.

Comment: But i think you have some mistake. $h_n$ is not in your way. Because when there are two variables, it will be $-\dfrac{1}{x+y}$. When there are 3 variables, it will be $\dfrac{1}{x+y+z}$. @CyclotomicField

Comment: Where does the problem come from? Do you *know* that the functions are convex or is it a conjecture?

Comment: @MartinR I am sure that the functions are convex. I checked $h_1, h_2, h_3$ by using hessian matrix but $h_n$ i can't do it because there are a lot of variables.

Comment: :( please help me